# Creating a JComboBox with only 1 item editable

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to create a JComboBox -lets say with 3 items in it -but only on of those will be editable from the user.The  setEditable(true) makes all of them editable.Is it possible?

Comment: please check the above comment, I think it is exactly same as your question

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44647027/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.